# java using BigInteger and While

Tags: java

I have a problem

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class medici {
   public static void main(String[] arg)  {
{     

  BigInteger zac = new BigInteger("3");
  zac = zac.pow(399);

  BigInteger kon = new BigInteger("3");
  kon = kon.pow(400); 

BigInteger nul = new BigInteger("0");
BigInteger jed = new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger detel = new BigInteger("3");


for (BigInteger a = zac; a.compareTo( kon ) <= 0; a = a.add(jed)) {


 cis = a ;      // THIS A PROBLEM
String retez = "";

 while ( cis > 0 );      // THIS IS A PROBLEM

retez = ( cis.mod(detel) ) + retez;

cis = cis.divide(detel);

         System.out.println(retez);

}      
}
}
}
```

I've tried this formula `BigInteger cis = new BigInteger("a");` for this `cis = a ;`

and `while ( cis.compareTo( nul ) >  0 );` for this `while ( cis > 0 );`

but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

When I use this formula, this is the same, but I used only integer when I use the same for Big Integer it doesn't work

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class netik {
   public static void main(String[] arg)  {
{          
int a ;
int cis;
int detel = 3;

for ( a = 567880; a <= 567890; a++ ){

cis = a;

String retez = "";

      while (cis > 0)  {

      retez = (cis % detel) + retez;

      cis /= detel;

      }
System.out.println(retez);    
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Where is `cis` declared?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do, exactly?

Comment: no where I dont know how to declare because I work with BigInteger and it is diferent.

Comment: the result is combination of numbers O,1, and 2 in the string try the second formula and you will see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare `cis` and store `a` into `cis` see the following:

```
BigInteger cis = new BigInteger(""+a);
```

Assuming this code is the main cause of your problems, and assuming `cis` is a `BigInteger`:

```
while (cis > 0)  {
    retez = (cis % detel) + retez;
    cis /= detel;
}
```

This should instead be: (This assumes everything is a `BigInteger`.

```
while (cis.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) > 0)  {
    retez = (cis.mod(detel)).add(retez);
    cis = cis.divide(detel);
}
```

---

The following code runs for me:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {

    BigInteger zac = new BigInteger("3");
    zac = zac.pow(399);

    BigInteger kon = new BigInteger("3");
    kon = kon.pow(400);

    BigInteger nul = new BigInteger("0");
    BigInteger jed = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger detel = new BigInteger("3");

    for (BigInteger a = zac; a.compareTo(kon) <= 0; a = a.add(jed)) {

        BigInteger cis = a; // THIS A PROBLEM
        String retez = "";

        while (cis.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) >= 0) {
            retez = (cis.mod(detel)) + retez;
            cis = cis.divide(detel);
            System.out.println(retez);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't produce the neatest results. But it runs.

Comment: retez = (cis.mod(detel)).add(retez);

Comment: @user, you need to declare `cis` outside of the loop.  See the top of my answer for how to do that.

Comment: BigInteger kon = new BigInteger("3"); kon = kon.pow(400); BigInteger zac = new BigInteger("3"); zac = zac.pow(399); BigInteger nul = new BigInteger("0"); BigInteger jed = new BigInteger("1"); BigInteger detel = new BigInteger("3"); for (BigInteger a = zac; a.compareTo( kon ) <= 0; a = a.add(jed)) { BigInteger cis = new BigInteger (""+a) ; String retez = ""; while ( cis.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) > 0 ); retez = ( cislo.mod(detel) ).add (retez); cis = cis.divide(detel); System.out.println(retez); } } } }

Comment: From the code you posted in the comment, it looks like `cis` was declared correctly.  Perhaps you should declare `cis` outside of the for loop too.  But, I'm not sure what's wrong with the code.

Comment: are you sure that I can use it this waywhile ( cis.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) > 0 );

Comment: if( cis > 0) break    or  something like that

Comment: @user, there really is no difference between using a `while` or and `if() break;`  It shouldn't matter which you choose.

Comment: @user, my guess is there is an error earlier in your code that is causing problems here.  But' I cannot be sure what the exact problem is.  Sorry.

Comment: Thank You, if You have any Idea to solve my code please answer to me

Comment: but when  I start to calculate nothing happend even when I put for loop very low pow(3) to mod(4). I dont believe that computer can calculate this very slow there is still some small part wrong

Comment: can You compile this code in Your computer and try to calculate in Your computer please?

Comment: @user, I am at work right now and am unable to compile and run your code.  Sorry.

Comment: OK maybe tomorow all the best to you

Comment: When I compile this code ,its written no errors, when run code it doesnt show anything.


import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class medici {
   public static void main(String[] arg)  {
{     
  BigInteger zac = new BigInteger("3");
  zac = zac.pow(399);   

  BigInteger kon = new BigInteger("3");
  kon = kon.pow(400); 
  

BigInteger jed = new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger detel = new BigInteger("3");

for (BigInteger a = zac; a.compareTo( kon ) <= 0; a = a.add(jed)) {


BigInteger cis = new BigInteger (""+a) ;

Comment: BigInteger cis = new BigInteger (""+a) ; 


String retez = "";


while ( cis.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) > 0 ); 

retez = ( cis.mod( detel )) + retez;
cis = cis.divide( detel );

         System.out.println(retez);
       
}      
}
}
}

I think that something is wrong here

retez = ( cis.mod( detel )) + retez;
cis = cis.divide( detel );
 
 The result is combinations of 0,1,2 in long string with more then 350 digits.

Comment: @user, it's in the answer that we are commenting on. (At the bottom)

Comment: while (cis.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) >= 0) {

Comment: while (cis.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) > 0) { 
 this is correct

Comment: @user, well, you should click the green check mark next to my answer to let others know that this was the answer that solved your problem

Comment: But there is a small problem. Very easy. You are almost there.

Comment: I show you the correct result and result from the code. please give me 10 minutes

Comment: @user, you should edit them into your original question so they can be formatted better.

Comment: I calculated with low numbers to be easy

Comment: from     for mod(1) to mod(3)

Comment: among the shown results are corect results this my goal good. I see them, but there are also results which must not be there

Comment: the amount of result must be 27, but I have 70 results among them are correct results

Comment: for pow(3) which is 27 result is 1000.

Comment: for 26 must be 222, but i have 2, 22, 222 each number in their own line I dont know hot to write here for individual line without using enter

Comment: for 25 result 221 but I have 1, 21, 221 also ind. line

Comment: It looks that     System.out.println(retez);      writes everything

Comment: but I need only the final result before code jump for another loop

Comment: @user, does it help if you move the print line down a line, right below the while loop?

Comment: }                                                  System.out.println(retez); 
}                                                                          I put it between } them,  and it works I got the dream results

Comment: My friend let me tell You again, You are the best from the best Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's hard to read.
From what I've gathered, cis isn't declared.  I assume you meant to have BigInteger cis; up there somewhere.  Please be more specific.  What type of problem are you receiving?  Compilation error?  Problem in what the program actually does?

Comment: Its written in compiler Icannot use this while ( cis > 0 );

Comment: I don know hot declare cis and put a to cis